# Facebook publish_pages long term token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Workflow of my application is following:
-User can log into system
-User retrieves user token which is (or should not be) saved to DB
-User selects one of his pages and requests token with publish_pages permission
-token is saved into DB
For next X amount of days(event months or years) facebook webhook triggers my API which uses that token to post response to graph API.

Is there any way to get longterm token or any refresh token api endpoint which would not require for user to log in each time when sessions expires to get another token?
Basicaly, this should serve as an app that will auto reply to comments on facebook page posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Page Tokens are valid forever, just use that one.

Information about how to generate an Extended Page Token can be found here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Steps:

- Get User token with `publish_pages` and `manage_pages`
- Extend User Token
- Get Extended Page Token by using the Extended User Token with `/me/accounts?fields=name,access_token`

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer :)